# Regex for relative filepath

Tags: c++, regex

I'm making a lexer for a statement like so,(C++ flex bison flavor):-

```
model @l1 ./something/city1.obj
```

For the .`/something/city1` part, I'm using the regex

```
"./"([[a-zA-Z0-9]+"/"]*)?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)
```

And yet I'm getting syntax errors. Why? My thought process was this:

- First, it checks for an exact match, forward slash is escaped, shouldn't be a problem.
- Next, it checks for `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` i.e a bunch of these. followed by a `/`. So the folders are done.
- Lastly, it checks for `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` which is a sort of valid file name.

Here's the surrounding code:

```
lexer.l
    %{
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string>
    #include "bisoner.tab.h"
    using namespace std;
    %}

    %%
    "Tax"                       return TAXTOKEN;
    "rent"                      return RENTTOKEN;
    "cost"                      return COSTTOKEN;
    "route"                     return RTOKEN;
    "Currency"                  return CURRENCYTOKEN;
    "StartingMoney"             return STARTINGMONEYTOKEN;
    "JailFine"                  return JAILFINETOKEN;
    "location"                  return LOCATIONWORD;
    "@l"                        return LTOKEN;
    "@g"                        return GTOKEN;
    "model"                     return MODELTOKEN;
    "#"[a-zA-Z0-9.-_= ]+            printf("comment ignored\n");
    [0-9]+                      yylval.number=atoi(yytext);return INTEGER;
    [a-zA-Z]+                   yylval.str=new string(yytext);return WORD;
    "./"([[a-zA-Z0-9]+"/"]*)?([a-zA-Z0-9]+) yylval.str=new string(yytext);return FILEPATHTOKEN;
    ".obj"                      return OBJEXTENSION;
    "%"                         return PERCENTSIGN;

    %%
```

bison.y

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include "rapidjson/document.h"
#include "rapidjson/writer.h"
#include "rapidjson/stringbuffer.h"
#include "Monopoly.h"
using namespace std;
extern int yylex();
extern void yyerror(char*);
Monopoly game;
void yyerror(const char *str)
{
        fprintf(stderr,"error: %s\n",str);
}


%}

%token LTOKEN INTEGER LOCATIONWORD WORD GTOKEN CURRENCYTOKEN JAILFINETOKEN STARTINGMONEYTOKEN RTOKEN COSTTOKEN RENTTOKEN FILEPATHTOKEN OBJEXTENSION MODELTOKEN TAXTOKEN PERCENTSIGN

%union{
  std::string *str;
  int number;
}
%token <number> INTEGER
%token <str> WORD
%token <str> FILEPATHTOKEN
%%
commands: /* empty */
        | command commands
        ;

command:
        currency_set
        |
        location_set
        |
        startingMoney_set
        |
        jailFine_set
        |
        route_add
        |
        cost_set
        |
        rent_set
        |
        filepath_found
        |
        tax_set
        ;
filepath_found:MODELTOKEN LTOKEN INTEGER FILEPATHTOKEN WORD OBJEXTENSION
        {
            string x=*($4)+*($5)+".obj";
            game.locations.at($3).locationOfObjectFile=x;
            printf(" File %s HAS BEEN IMPORTED for location number %d \n",x.c_str(),$3 );

        }

rent_set:RENTTOKEN LTOKEN INTEGER INTEGER INTEGER INTEGER INTEGER INTEGER INTEGER   
        {
            printf("rent for house no 4 is %d \n",$7);
        } 
cost_set:COSTTOKEN LTOKEN INTEGER INTEGER INTEGER INTEGER INTEGER INTEGER INTEGER INTEGER
        {
            printf("prices set to %d\n",$10 );
        }
currency_set:CURRENCYTOKEN WORD
            {

                game.currency=*($2);
            }

location_set:
            LOCATIONWORD LTOKEN INTEGER WORD GTOKEN INTEGER
            {
            Location newCity;
            newCity.locationNo=$3;
            newCity.name=*($4);
            newCity.group=$6;
            game.locations.push_back(newCity);
            printf("new city %d named %s in group %d\n",newCity.locationNo,newCity.name.c_str(),newCity.group );
            }
startingMoney_set:
            STARTINGMONEYTOKEN INTEGER
            {
                game.startingMoney=$2;

            printf("starting money set to %f \n",game.startingMoney);
            }
jailFine_set:
            JAILFINETOKEN INTEGER
            {
                game.jailFine=$2;
                printf("jailfine set to %f\n",game.jailFine);
            }

route_add:
            RTOKEN LTOKEN INTEGER LTOKEN INTEGER
            {
                game.graph[$3][$5]=true;
                printf("Route set up between location no %d \n",game.graph[$3][$5]);
            }

tax_set:
        TAXTOKEN INTEGER PERCENTSIGN INTEGER
        {
            game.taxPercent=$2;
            printf("tax set to %f percent\n",game.taxPercent );
        }


%%


int yywrap()
{
        return 1;
} 
extern FILE * yyin;

int bisonParser()
{
    yyin=fopen("csp301_configFile.txt","r");
    yyparse();

    std::cout<<game.currency.c_str();
    string json="{ \"hello\" : \"world\"} ";
    rapidjson::Document d;
    d.Parse<0>(json.c_str());

    printf("%s\n", d["hello"].GetString());
    return 1;
}
```

How does this not work?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the quotation marks in the regex? Are you getting syntax errors when compiling or when running?

Comment: Having had a closer look at your ‘regex’ it looks like you should start with a regex tutorial. There are multiple issues in your current attempt. As for the quotation marks I'm guessing you've either gotten the idea that regex is a built-in type (which it is not in C++ (as it is in e.g. Perl)) or you think it's a means of escaping things (which it is not). It would be good if you could show us the surrounding code.

Comment: Syntax error while running. Probably because it didn't match the target string.

Comment: No, a syntax error and not matching are *completely* different things. Could you show us some code? And does the error have any more information?

Comment: Nope. Absolutely nothin

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, this works for relative filepaths.

```
"./"([[a-zA-Z0-9]+"/"]*)?               return FILEPATHTOKEN;
```